# JQuery Button - Maintain height when text removed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a button which I style using [jQuery's UI's button](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button).

```
<button class="widget-button">Submit</button>
```

Based on certain events this button can have its text cleared.

```
$('.widget-button').button('option', 'label', '');
```

When this occurs the button's height becomes smaller. I would like to maintain the button's height even when no text is shown.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: And, ideally, what does your jQuery script look like that clears the `button` text, in response to what? It might be possible to work with the functions to provide some sort of variable that can be used to persist the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but, I think, should work (and without seeing your html I can't offer anything better):

```
$('.widget-button').css('height', $(this).height()).button('option', 'label', '');
```

This should, in theory, assign the current `height` as an inline-style to the `.widget-button` before clearing the text. You could, of course, also use a `data-` prefixed custom attribute:

```
$('.widget-button').attr('data-buttonHeight',$(this).height()).button('option','label','');
```

But, as noted, this is untested. If you can post your mark-up, and the jQuery code you're working with to clear the `button`'s text we might be able to offer better answers.

Comment: This is more robust than some other answers where you try to match the jQuery-UI css height with new CSS rules - the jQuery-UI values may very well change if you upgrade or re-themify.

Comment: The question presented is not one that calls for a "robust" or "dynamic" solution. OP asks to to make it stay the same. For this purpose jquery and javascript are ill suited. They are great tools for managing changes in the ui at runtime, but are wasted cycles for setting a property that is not going to change during the page's client life cycle. Using CSS or style elements here makes sure that the size of an object is fixed and that is what is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your CSS:

```
.widget-button { min-height: 23px }
```

Set the `min-height` to whatever you want, I think 23px is the standard for most of jQuery UI.  `min-width` is also available if you want to set a width too.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, jQuery UI's button heights are relative to the size of text within. As such, the min-height CSS solutions will give the button height, but it likely won't be exactly what the height was with the text--which likely varies from browser to browser and installed font to installed font causing a visual shift in height when the text is cleared.

As such, I would not use CSS as a solution but rather instead of clearing out the text, replace it with an `&nbsp;`

(all that said, I would be curious as to what one would do with a blank button from a UI/UX perspective)

Comment: This is what I am finding. Although the css min-height does adjust the height slightly, the button with text has a height slightly larger due to font-size.

Comment: oops...my `&nbsp;` didn't show up the first time. My answer probably makes a bit more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Just define proper value of `min-height` for that button in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with pure CSS, and always have value of the button (which is good when it comes to screen-readers etc.

```
.widget-button { text-indent: -9999px; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely would do what I need, however I don't really want the value sticking around.

Answer (score 0):

use the min-height "hack" so that it works in all browsers:

```
.selector{
     min-height:23px; 
     height:auto !important;
     height:23px
}
```

where min-height and the second height is the height you want the element to be minimum

Answer (score 0):

since you are identifying the button (or buttons) by class you may either use that class as a css class and set a fixed height or a min height like this.

```
.widget-button
        {
            height:25px; 
        }    

.widget-button
        {
            min-height:25px; 
        }
```

or if you are wanting to seperate class names used by jquery from class names used for css you can go with

```
.widget-button-ui
        {
            height:25px;
        }
```

and apply multiple class names to the object like:

```
<input type="button" id="demobutton" class="widget-button widget-button-ui" value="Hello World" />
```

final option, fix it in the mark up like:

```
<input type="button" id="demobutton" class="widget-button" value="Hello World" style="min-height:23px;" />
```

the way styles are applied, the style value in the markup itself will take precedence.